# Gridx works fine until VirtualVScroller module is added. Then only shows "loading..."

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo.gridx, gridx

When I add the Gridx module "VirtualVScroller" to my Grid, only "loading..." and no data is shown. Without the module everything works just fine. I already tried to remove all other modules, but this doesn't help either.
Any ideas for my code below?:

```
require([
    "gridx/Grid",
    "gridx/core/model/cache/Sync",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "gridx/modules/CellWidget", 
    "gridx/modules/Bar",
    "gridx/modules/Filter", 
    "gridx/modules/filter/QuickFilter",
    "gridx/modules/ColumnResizer", 
    "gridx/modules/SingleSort",
    "gridx/modules/VirtualVScroller",
    "gridx/modules/ColumnWidth",
    "gridx/modules/HScroller",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Grid, Cache, Memory,CellWidget,Bar,Filter, QuickFilter, ColumnResizer,SingleSort,VirtualVScroller,ColumnWidth,HScroller,Button){

         var myButton = new Button({
            label: "new",
            onClick: function(){
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        });

        var store = new Memory({
            idProperty:"itemID",
            data: datajson
        });
        var grid = new Grid({
                id:"gridId",
                store: store,
                cacheClass: Cache,
                structure: structurejson,
                autoWidth: true,
                barTop: [
                    [{plugin: myButton}],
                    [{pluginClass: "gridx/support/QuickFilter", style: "text-align: right;"}]

                ],
                modules: [
                "gridx/modules/VirtualVScroller",
                "gridx/modules/CellWidget",
                "gridx/modules/Bar",
                "gridx/modules/select/Row",
                "gridx/modules/select/Cell",
                "gridx/modules/Filter",
                "gridx/modules/ColumnResizer",
                "gridx/modules/SingleSort",
                "gridx/modules/ColumnWidth",
                "gridx/modules/HScroller"
            ]
            });
            grid.placeAt("content");
            grid.startup();


    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after hours of testing and debugging I was wondering that my code was working on fiddle, but not in my own environment. The problem was a custom gridx stylesheet, which obviously had some error. The code above is correct, I will now have to take care of the css file.